# How to increment value up to pre defined value, using hex limit (16) with maximum of 16 numbers/chars? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, hex, increment

I am trying to increment a seed up to 16 maximum (using hex: 0123456789ABCEDF) with a limit of 16 numbers/chars.

Something like a function that generates the result in ranges like:

between 0 and 33, the result shoul be:

```
0: "0000000000000000"
1: "0000000000000001"
2: "0000000000000002"
3: "0000000000000003"
4: "0000000000000004"
5: "0000000000000005"
6: "0000000000000006"
7: "0000000000000007"
8: "0000000000000008"
9: "0000000000000009"
10: "000000000000000A"
11: "000000000000000B"
12: "000000000000000C"
13: "000000000000000D"
14: "000000000000000E"
15: "000000000000000F"
16: "0000000000000010"
17: "0000000000000011"
18: "0000000000000012"
19: "0000000000000013"
20: "0000000000000014"
21: "0000000000000015"
22: "0000000000000016"
23: "0000000000000017"
24: "0000000000000018"
25: "0000000000000019"
26: "000000000000001A"
27: "000000000000001B"
28: "000000000000001C"
29: "000000000000001D"
30: "000000000000001E"
31: "000000000000001F"
32: "0000000000000020"
33: "0000000000000021"
```

I already made a random function to generate the seeds (which is more easy). But if I want to generate them in order how should I proceed?

The random function:

```js
function makeid(length) {
      let result           = '';
      result += "0x";
      var characters       = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var charactersLength = characters.length;
      for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      }
      return result;
    }
    let seeds = ""
    
    let number = 50;
    
    function genSeeds(number){
      for(let s=0;s<number;s++){
        seeds+= "<span>"+makeid(16)+"</span><br>"
      }
      $('.result').html(seeds);
    }
    
    genSeeds(number);
```

```css
.result {
  font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the question is, what is the input and what is the desired output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to get the same result I get with the random function but instead of random, in order like the example above, but of a given range. Example, if I wanted to generate from 10 to 20, the first item of the array should be `000000000000000A` and the last `0000000000000014`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function which add one to a given hex string.

```js
function inc(hex) {
    var carry = 1;
    return [...hex].reduceRight((r, v) => {
        r.unshift(((carry += parseInt(v, 16)) % 16).toString(16));
        carry >>= 4;
        return r;
    }, []).join('');
}

var value = '000000000000000A',
    count = 10;

while (count--) console.log(value = inc(value));
```

Comment: Exactly the result I was looking for. Thank you Nina!

Comment: Wouldn't the increment be simpler and a lot more efficient with something like: `const inc = (hex) => (parseInt(hex, 16) + 1).toString(16).padStart(16, '0').toUpperCase()`

Comment: Hey @Cristy I like your approach, do you know if can I turn this into a function that runs from range x to range y?

Comment: Hey @Cristy done, I made a range function to work with your function! `function rangeadd(x,y){
  let seed = [];
  while(x<y){
    seed.push(hexadd(x));
    x = x + 1;
  }
  return seed;
}` thank you too :)